# Error occurred in loading omnisharp from omnisharp.path Could not start the server due to Error: Invalid OmniSharp version - omnisharp.path:latest

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, omnisharp

I have a problem. I downloaded the **netcore** project with **version 3.1.101**, but I am getting an error like this.

[image: error]

None of the solutions I tried on the internet worked.

Comment: what is 'the netcore project'? Did you install the C# extension for VSCode? Ctrl+Shift+P, then type 'omni' and select 'OmniSharp: Restart OmniSharp'. Also try restarting VSCode (same key binding, but select 'Developer: Restart Window'). C# extionsion Id is 'ms-dotnettools.csharp'

Comment: .NET core... Yes i did but not working. I guess there is a problem with the .NET Core SDK